# Java: What member value returned on unimplemented abstract method?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, member, extends

In Java, if I have a class such as this

```
abstract class TestClass
{
    int mMember = 0;

    int getMember()
    {
        return mMember;
    }
}
```

and a class that extends this class:

```
class TestExtended extends TestClass
{
     int mMember = 1;
}
```

If I create an instance of TestExtended, and call **testExtended.getMember();** would it return 0, or 1?

In other words, when I extend a class, and don't override a method from said class, does it call the method and act on the members in said class, or in the extended class?

Would I need to re-implement (copy-paste) the function in the extended class to get the function to return 1?

Comment: Why not just test this? (It will return `0`, by the way.)

Comment: I couldn't find an answer on StackOverflow. I didn't know the answer myself, and thought it would benefit others by asking it. I don't have access to a compiler, so I can't test it now. Thanks to all those people voting me down on a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return `0`, not `1`.

This is because you cannot "override" fields from a superclass. You can set them, so long as they are not `private`, but if you declare a new variable with the same name, it will simply shadow the superclass variable.

On the other hand, you *can* override methods.

Now, shadowing member variables in this way is usually a Very Bad Idea™, and is another reason to avoid public fields. This is why:

```
TestExtended sub = new TestExtended();
sub.mMember = 5;
System.out.println(sub.mMember); // prints '5', as expected

TestClass sup = sub; // this is fine, TestExtended extends TestClass
System.out.println(sup.mMember); // prints '0'!
```

The compiler will choose which version of the variable to use based on the compile-time type, breaking polymorphism. Don't shadow member variables, and avoid public fields, and this will never matter. Use getters and setters instead.

Answer (score 1):

It can be confirmed by running. It will return `0`. This is because the fields cannot be overridden. What you are actually doing is `hiding` the instance variable as per jls.

> overriding of methods differs from hiding of fields (§8.3), for it is
>   permissible for a field to hide a field of another type.

Check Example 8.4.8.3-4. in [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) for more info

To get the subclass version, you would have to:

```
 class TestExtended extends TestClass
     {
     int mMember = 1;

     @Override
     int getMember(){
          return mMember;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Base class methods cannot access subclass fields (at least, without using reflection). Full stop.

Also, fields do not participate in overriding, unlike methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using `testExtended.getMember();` obviously means you are calling the abstract class method because you dont override the method in your sub-class. if you would have overridden it then the preference would have been given to subclass method first if your object is of type subclass. so in this case it will give you 0 unless you override the method.